# Authentication in shiny app and multiple pages

Tags: r, authentication, passwords, shiny

In the system that I am developing I have 3 different actors (user, admin, support team) using Shiny App. I want to know how I can give authentication to these three actors that each of these actor only access to their page. I found that It can be possible with shiny server Pro which is not free. Is there any way to do it instead of using shiny server pro. In the UI.R the code are as following:

```
  library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
rm(list = ls())


Logged = FALSE;
my_username <- "test"
my_password <- "test"

ui1 <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(


  box(




    ui = (htmlOutput("page"))

   )
  )
)
```

In the Server.R the codes are as following:
library(shinydashboard)

library(shiny)

```
server = (function(input, output,session) {

  ui1 <- function(){
    tagList(
      div(id = "login",
          wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                    passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                    br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
      tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
    )}

  ui2 <- function(){tagList(tabPanel("Test"))}
  USER <<- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
      })
      print(ui)
    }
  })
})
```

I want to go to another page that is only authenticated to user . How can I connect the UI.R to different pages in shiny App? (For example show the page USER.R).

Comment: I want to have multiple files and page instead of writing all commands in ui.r and server.r

Comment: I think you can create different r file with list of needed UI elements and then use source on this files in if-else  `output$page <- renderUI({ if(user.role=="user") source(user.r)
list_from_source
      })`

Comment: can you please give a simple example that I can try it

Comment: can you please tell me where is my error that the following code does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try such
i think it can help to do what you want

1) ui :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyUI( 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(

        uiOutput("page")

    )
  )

)
```

2) server :

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    source("user.R")
    source("admin.R")

    my_username <- c("test","admin")
    my_password <- c("test","123")
    get_role=function(user){
      if(user=="test") {
        return("TEST")
      }else{
        return("ADMIN")
      }
    }

    get_ui=function(role){
      if(role=="TEST"){
        return(list_field_user)
      }else{
        return(list_field_admin)
      }
    }


    shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

      USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE,role=NULL)

      ui1 <- function(){
        tagList(
          div(id = "login",
              wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                        passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                        br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in")))
          ,tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -10px;margin-left: -150px;}")
        )}

      ui2 <- function(){list(tabPanel("Test",get_ui(USER$role)[2:3]),get_ui(USER$role)[[1]])}

      observe({ 
        if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
          if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
            if (input$Login > 0) {
              Username <- isolate(input$userName)
              Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
              Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
              Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
              if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
                if (Id.username == Id.password) {
                  USER$Logged <- TRUE
                  USER$role=get_role(Username)

              }
            } 
          }
        }
        }
      })
      observe({
        if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

          output$page <- renderUI({
box(
            div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1()))))
          })
        }
        if (USER$Logged == TRUE)    {
          output$page <- renderUI({
box(width = 12,
            div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
          )})
          #print(ui)
        }
      })
    })
```

3) user.r:

```
 list_field_user = list(tabPanel("test2",fluidRow(column(6,numericInput("inputtest", "test", value = 0),column(6,actionButton(inputId ="test1",label ="go"))))),
                       h1("1234"),h2("234"))
```

4) admin.r

```
list_field_admin = list( h1("admin"),h2("admin"))
```

!!! place all this files in one dir

that simple example but this can help you

Comment: You have problem in `css` and i think you not need `ui = (htmlOutput("page"))` in ui , i use ` uiOutput("page")` , and you not need `<<-` for reactive value ,other i get from your code

Comment: Thank you so much awesome. yes you are right . It works very well.

Comment: can we add some widgets and controls in user.r and admin.r ?

Comment: How can I change the width of new page, because it is same as width of wellpanel in login page?

Comment: Problem that you have "page" into box ( in you ui). Edit fro what you need i think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. it helps a lot. I have another question which I have posted in the following link can you please read this Question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820575/how-to-add-edit-delete-of-table-in-shiny-app

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text is an incredibly bad practice, as is making the default behavior granting admin rights. This setup looks extremely unsafe.