# Create a log in screen for shiny app without shiny server

Tags: r, password-protection, shiny-server, shiny

I am fairly new to Shiny, but have created an app which I am hosting locally without shiny server.

What I'd like to do, is create a log in screen, which means that only authorised users can access my app.

Is there a way to do this? I have only found examples which use the shiny server, and this is something I do not want to do. I have also read something about Apache Web Server, but I wasn't sure how to do this, or if I needed to download something to get this set up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: " hosting locally without shiny server" - how exactly?

Comment: Using the `runApp(host="0.0.0.0", port=1000)` command, other local users can then access my app using my IP address and port. Not sure if I phrased the 'hosting locally' right, but that's what I mean.

Comment: there is some ways ( but not good) .. you can create reactiveValue for check loged user or not .. see [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796585/authentication-in-shiny-app-and-multiple-pages)  and [2](http://withr.me/authentication-of-shiny-server-application-using-a-simple-method/)